# Error 404 with POST ajax in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've a route defined this way:

```
order_request:
class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
options:
model:                OrderRequest
module:               order
prefix_path:          /order
column:               id
with_wildcard_routes: true
```

Trying to post data from a form with ajax this way.

```
$.post('order/1578/exportPostsToProject', jsonString, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

1578 is the Id of the order. The Id is not strictly required but it's there.
But the problem is that as soon as I try do do the ajax request with POST i get this error:

```
POST http://184.95.x.xx/backend.php/order/1578/exportPostsToProject 404 (Not Found)
```

If I change the POST in GET the error doesn't appear and all works properly.
How can I solve this problem ? I need to POST the data.

my controller:

```
public function executeExportPostsToProject(sfWebRequest $request)
{

    $orderRequest = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->order_request = $orderRequest;
    $this->orderPostList = $orderRequest->getOrderGeneratedPosts();

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
   {
        $settingsString = $request->getParameter('settingsStr');
   }
}
```

Comment: Is your server-side method expecting GET or POST?  If it's expecting POST data, then GET shouldn't work.

Comment: How can I check this ? I edited the question and added the controller definition in the controller Action.

Comment: Can you show me more code as to how you are handling the `$request` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an [object route](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/10-Routing#chapter_10_sub_object_actions) to the collection which explicitly allows POST requests. E.g:

```
order_request:
    class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
    options:
        model:                OrderRequest
        module:               order
        prefix_path:          /order
        column:               id
        with_wildcard_routes: true
        object_actions:
            export: [get, post]
```

Comment: and can I add Get too ?

Comment: Nothing I tryet with object_actions and the problem seems to remain

Comment: I updated my answer, but please look at the linked docs as well. With this example the route looks like this: order_request_export and the generated url should look like this: /order/:id/export (order/1578/export).

Comment: That was. Thank you very much. object_actions and the correct url_for was the answer.